# How do you display SQL Select output from CL?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I am trying to replace an old CL program that issues `RUNQRY` command.

I can run the SQL statement from `STRSQL` and it will yield the same output as the query.

I tried `RUNSQL` and `RUNSQLSTM` but neither support just doing a `SELECT`

Is there a command to just display the output of SQL select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Query Manager (STRQM)` is the SQL based green screen replacement for Query/400.  Manuals can be found here: [Query Manager Use](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v6r1/en_US/sc415212.pdf?view=kc&origURL=ssw_ibm_i_61/rzatc/sc415212.pdf) and [Query Management Programming](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/systems/power/docs/systemi/v6r1/en_US/sc415703.pdf?view=kc&origURL=ssw_ibm_i_61/rzatc/sc415703.pdf)

Queries can be created via a Query/400 like "prompted mode" or simply by entering SQL directly.

Once a QM query has been defined, the `Start Query Management Query (STRQMQRY)` command can be used in CL to run it and includes an `OUTPUT` parameter that can be `*` (to display), `*PRINT`, or `*OUTFILE`.

**Another Option**
[The QSHELL Db2 utility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahz/rzahzdb2utility.htm)

```
STRQSH CMD('db2 ''select table_name, table_owner from qsys2.systables limit 1''')
```

Make sure that the environment variable QIBM_QSH_CMD_OUTPUT doesn't exist with a value of `NONE` and you'll get a `Press ENTER to end terminal session.` message at the bottom of your results.